# How to consume JSON response with spring restemplate properly?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, restful-url

I have a Spring MVC Rest service that return JSON value, i have 8 row, here is my JSON

```
[
{"no":"1","date":"2015-03-30","grandtotal":699618,"diskon":699618},
{"no":"2","date":"2015-03-30","grandtotal":1867949,"diskon":1867949},
{"no":"3","date":"2015-03-27","grandtotal":2190909,"diskon":2190909},
{"no":"4","date":"2015-03-26","grandtotal":8616120,"diskon":8616120},
{"no":"5","date":"2015-03-26","grandtotal":1095455,"diskon":1095455},
{"no":"6","date":"2015-03-24","grandtotal":938961,"diskon":938961},
{"no":"7","date":"2015-03-24","grandtotal":5603848,"diskon":5603848},
{"no":"8","date":"2015-03-20","grandtotal":3735899,"diskon":3735899}
]
```

What i trying.. Here is my controller. SpringRestController.java
Jackson Way :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initCreationForm(Map<String, Object> model) {

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceJson/view/";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    TotalDiscList totaldisc = restTemplate.getForObject(url, TotalDisc.class);


    model.put("DiscValue",totaldisc);
    return "salesorders/totalDisc";
}
```

Gson way :

```
public String initCreationForm(Map<String, Object> model) {

String url = "http://localhost:8080/SpringServiceJson/view/";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Collection<TotalDisc> totaldisc = gson.fromJson(url, PiutangListJson.class);



    model.put("DiscValue",totaldisc);
    return "salesorders/totalDisc";
}
```

what i missed here? it always give me this error 
**"Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Lorg.springframework.samples.my.model.TotalDiscList;] and content type [application/json]"**

Here is my object TotalDiscList.java

```
public class TotalDiscList {

    private String no;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date date;
    private long grandtotal;
    private long diskon;

//getter setter skipped
}
```

i should return `List<TotalDiscList> totaldisc = restTemplate.getForObject(url, List<TotalDisc>.class);` right?
how i do that properly?

Comment: Just return a list. But the JSON you return doesn't match the class properties you have. In JSON you have `no` and your object `no_faktur`. Those don't match. Instead of a `List` you could try an `TotalDiscList[]` instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry i copied wrong class property.. i just updated my answer

Comment: @M.Deinum so here is my code, i populate my code with your suggestion TotalDiscList[] totaldisc = restTemplate.getForObject(url, TotalDiscList[].class); it still give me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

You need to provide a Message converter to your `RestTemplate`

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
```

And then try using an array, such as:

```
TotalDiscList[] totaldisc = restTemplate
                    .getForObject(url, TotalDiscList[].class);
```

Comment: i already done that, it's still give me the same error, i put my code in my comment above

Comment: still failed.. it give me error 500 "Servlet.service() for servlet [myproject] in context with path [/myproject] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonProcessingException] with root cause"

Comment: That error message means that it's being processed by Jackson (though org.codehaus is the package for Jackson 1.x, not 2.x which has com.fasterxml), you need to look at the stacktrace and try to figure out what's wrong. It's likely either malformed JSON or your object model doesn't map correctly to the JSON you're receiving.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a servlet-context.xml, you can add the message-convertor there, like below :

```
 <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters" ref="jsonMessageConverter" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
```

I am doing the same and it works.

Comment: Dont go on the name, do you have something like application-context.xml...same code for that.

Comment: thank you, it worked ! dafuq i have stuck for a week! thank u so muchhh

Comment: but i choose shadowray as my answer yet i give u my 50 point, cause i do the same that he told me too.. both your code help me out, thank u so much

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure a json message converter:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
       <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and then, you can just annotate your method:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public TotalDiscList[] createDiscList(
         @RequestBody TotalDiscList[] object) {

   }
```

which would cause the message converter to try to convert to the given class.